# Label not showing validation output after clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a simple form validation page, but whenever I click on the Submit button, it doesn't display the label, after validating input from the text input field (in this case E-mail).

Here is the code:

```js
  function validate()
    {
        var regexp = new RegExp("/^([A-Za-z0-9_\.\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\.\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/");
        if(regexp.test(document.getElementById("emailInput").value))
        {
             document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = 'Invalid Format!';
        }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<title> Abdul Basit's Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter your details:</legend>

    Name: <input type="text"><br/><br/>
    Email: <input type="text" id="emailInput"><br/>
    <label id="email"></label><br /><br />
    CNIC: <input type="text"><br/>
    <label id="cnic"></label><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">

    </fieldset>
</form>
</center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you should use post submit

Comment: you might find solution here:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/5285062

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an email address be validated in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-can-an-email-address-be-validated-in-javascript)